# Firebase database node property value getting truncated in Chrome, Edge

Tags: firebase, google-chrome, firebase-realtime-database, microsoft-edge, firebase-console

Started working on Firebase database just recently, and node property value is getting truncated.

Which is why sometimes, it's difficult to understand the type of value.

For e.g. the below value are all strings, however, since the ending quotation is not showing, it's confusing.

Also one value is not fully visible.

---

**Chrome: 72.0.3626.121**

[image]

---

**Edge 42.17134.1.0**

[image]

---

**Looks OK in Firefox 65.0.1**

[image]

---

**Windows 10 64-bit**

Is this a browser issue? I'd like to work with Chrome.

Comment: I try to make a test with sample firebase database but did not find any option to see the data in tree structure format. can you please try to provide steps which can help to produce the issue. We will try to test the issue on our end and try to check the result. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Hi @Deepak-MSFT. The tree structure shows by default, initially collapsed, there's a '+' beside the root node, if you expand, you'll see child nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This indeed looks like a browser-specific rendering issue. I have it in Chrome too occasionally, but aren't too bothered by it (since the data is stored correctly).

It might be worth [filing a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), so that the UI engineers who build this know that this occurs on a specific browser.